# Java Jersey 2: standalone?

Tags: java, jersey

Is it possible to have a Jersey REST service standalone in a java application?
Every example I find is in the context of a webcontainer (web.xml).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just follow the [Jersey docs getting started](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/getting-started.html). It creates a standalone using Grizzly server. With Maven, you can easily create it with the following archetype command.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.27
```

The last argument `-DarchetypeVersion` can be replaced with any 2.x version you want. Currently, the latest is 2.27.

After running this command, you will have a generated main class you run from the command line.

---

Another way is to use [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) (which a lot of people are using), you can check out [the official example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey) and check out [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jersey)

---

#### Update

If you're not using Maven, below are all the jars that are pulled in with the archetype. Most are included in the [Jersey RI bundle you download from the docs](https://jersey.github.io/download.html). Just figure out the ones that are not in the bundle and search for those.

[image]

I think the ones not included in the RI bundle DL, are

- grizzly-framework
- grizzly-http
- grizzly-http-server
- jersey-container-grizzly2-http

And here are all the generated classes from the archetype.

**com.example.MyResource**

```
package com.example;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

**com.example.Main**

```
package com.example;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

/**
 * Main class.
 *
 */
public class Main {
    // Base URI the Grizzly HTTP server will listen on
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/";

    /**
     * Starts Grizzly HTTP server exposing JAX-RS resources defined in this application.
     * @return Grizzly HTTP server.
     */
    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
        // in com.example package
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.example");

        // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
        // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HttpServer server = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

**(test) com.example.MyResourceTest**

```
package com.example;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MyResourceTest {

    private HttpServer server;
    private WebTarget target;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // start the server
        server = Main.startServer();
        // create the client
        Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        // uncomment the following line if you want to enable
        // support for JSON in the client (you also have to uncomment
        // dependency on jersey-media-json module in pom.xml and Main.startServer())
        // --
        // c.configuration().enable(new org.glassfish.jersey.media.json.JsonJaxbFeature());

        target = c.target(Main.BASE_URI);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        server.stop();
    }

    /**
     * Test to see that the message "Got it!" is sent in the response.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetIt() {
        String responseMsg = target.path("myresource").request().get(String.class);
        assertEquals("Got it!", responseMsg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it with grizzly. As far I see it is not in the lastest jersey bundle (jaxrs-ri-2.27.zip). I just found jars with a google search but I think I have some version conflicts there. Is there an official package somewhere for grizzly? I do not using maven so it is a bit of handcraft.

Comment: I updated my answer to show all the jars that pulled in by the archetype and also posted all the generated classes.