# How to make executable file for deploy Maven java web project with rest api to server

Tags: java, rest, maven, web-deployment, jersey-2.0

I Made a java maven project for rest api .. 
now i need to deploy it on server .. that's why i wanted to make a executable jar .. How can i make this....?

Here i used Jersey-2 for rest api.
  [image: Project File Structure]

Maven Plugin:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>net.javatutorial.tutorials.services.FileUploadService</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an executable jar, your Jersey app needs to be a standalone app, which is an app that runs from a "main" class with a `main` method. To easily create a standalone app, you can use the Maven archetype mentioned in the [Jersey Getting Started](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#new-from-archetype). (You can see the generated files from the archetype in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50973184/2587435)).

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.27
```

Once you have your standalone app, then you can build it with the `maven-shade-plugin` like you are currently doing. The `Main` class is what you should specify in the `<mainClass>` element. One thing I should mention is that you should also use the `ServicesResourceTransformer` to concatenate the services files<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1 - See [Jersey fails when creating uber jar with maven-assembly-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36687312/2587435)</sub>